# Annotation Like @Primary in Spring Boot for Quarkus

Tags: java, dependency-injection, quarkus

Is there any equivalent annotation like @Primary in Spring Boot for Quarkus?
I found @DefaultBean but it does not work!!!

Answer (score 1):

Quarkus uses a CDI implementation for dependency injection. So, you have to use `@Default` and [@Alternative](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/index.html?javax/inject/Inject.html) annotations. **Please note:** In CDI, `@Default` is always set, behind the scenes, on beans which have  no other qualifier. That’s why you have to set `@Alternative` on every bean which you do not want to be the default one!

Answer (score 0):

use [@javax.inject.Qualifier](https://cn.quarkus.io/guides/cdi#you-talked-about-some-qualifiers).
works fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).